# Detect when shadow copy is complete

Tags: c#, mef, appdomain

So I have an application using MEF and an app domain set up to shadow copy assemblies. I have a source directory that is being watched by a `FileSystemWatcher` in order to trigger a refresh of the `DirectoryCatalog` when a new file is added. In my handler for the watcher events (`Changed`,`Created` and `Deleted`) I have something like this:

```
dirCatalog.Refresh();
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Where `dirCatalog` is my `DirectoryCatalog` and `_container` is my `CompositionContainer`. The problem is that sometimes it's not picking up the new assembly and *I think* it's a race condition problem. It never seems to be a problem if I debug and step through the code and I think it's because it's had enough time to make the shadow copy. So I could just throw in a `Thread.Sleep` or similar and hope that it'll have enough time to complete the copy before refreshing, but I'd like to know if there is a reliable way to *know* if the newly added assembly has been shadow copied before calling `Refresh` and `ComposeParts`?